# Cross-domain sitemap in robots.txt

Tags: cross-domain, blogger, robots.txt, google-search-console

I want to submit a Google Webmaster Tools sitemap for a Blogger "blog" that only consists of static pages (using it as a website instead of a blog).

Since there's no way for me to host a file on the Blogger server, and therefore no way to submit a sitemap directly through Google Webmaster Tools, is it possible to host a `sitemap.txt` file on another server and reference it in `robots.txt`? Or would I run into some sort of cross-domain issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can managed to map `robots.txt` file to your root directory, Which is `www.domain.com/robots.txt` thats okay, but i don't think you have to do that. Just add your site to Google Webmasters Tools and use regular seo strategy. Google is smart enough to Index your static pages.

--Hope this helps!!